# How to use django admin many to many field selector widget

Tags: django, django-admin, django-widget

I want to use this [image: Many to many field]

How can I use it for my many to many modelform. **Basically I want the add button**, which allows me to add the many to many objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of that "add" button is actually admin-specific.

In simple terms, you may use the wrapper located in `django.contrib.admin.widgets.RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper`. Consider what `django.contrib.admin.options` does:

```
formfield.widget = widgets.RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(
    formfield.widget, db_field.rel, self.admin_site,
    can_add_related=can_add_related)
```

But that requires you to use admin-specific objects, such as `admin_site`, the admin javascript ans css files and urls. I would recommend you build your own "Add" interface, even if based on this wrapper.